# Need an suggestion to map values using Java collection. Please suggest

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

We have a configuration where each property maps to two values in the DB,

Ex:

```
Property Name           Min Value           Max Value

VSMSSUB                   100                500
EEVMSSUB                  100                500
```

Now, What collection can be used to store the property and there min & max value ? HashMap is not possible since it is one to one.

or

Can I declare like this ?

HashMap

or

Need to use beans ?

Please suggest your recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` with the property name as the key and a composite object holding the min and max as value. Example:

```
public class Value {
   private int minValue;
   private int maxValue;

   public Value(int min, int max) {
      minValue = min;
      maxValue = max;
   }
}
```

Then create a `HashMap` as:

```
HashMap<String, Value> map = new HashMap<String, Value>();
```

and add key-values:

```
map.put("VSMSSUB", new Value(100, 500);
map.put("EEVMSSUB", new Value(100, 500);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a composite object with min-max values stored in it as fields.

```
class MinMax {
    private int min;
    private int max;
    //getters, setters
}

Map<String, MinMax> map = new HashMap<String, MinMax>();
```

This is a common practice and does not look ugly at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can change Integer to your data type

```
HashMap<String, Integer[]>
HashMap<String, YourBeanClass>  // (YourBeanClass has min and max members)
HashMap<String, List<Integer>>
```

Comment: Thank @Max, I made a typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think that as stated by other answers you are facing a very common use case and that the Bean solution is far from being an antipattern... In different applications I used such strategy adding even more data with fields like default value or average value (which is not always the mathematical average value) but the most frequently used ...
So using classes like

```
public class DefaultChoicesBean <T> {
private T minValue;
private T maxValue;
private T medianValue;
private T defaultValue;
public T getMinValue() {
    return minValue;
}
public void setMinValue(T minValue) {
    this.minValue = minValue;
}
public T getMaxValue() {
    return maxValue;
}
public void setMaxValue(T maxValue) {
    this.maxValue = maxValue;
}
public T getMedianValue() {
    return medianValue;
}
public void setMedianValue(T medianValue) {
    this.medianValue = medianValue;
}
public T getDefaultValue() {
    return defaultValue;
}
public void setDefaultValue(T defaultValue) {
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
}
}
```

you can use generics to avoid writing the same code several times...
This class fits well to applications learning with past user choices , so median values can be an auto adatptative one...

Hope this helps

Jerome

Comment: Well, I really disagree with you on using generics to store domain data. Each domain should have it's own specific objects, that makes the system decoupled and easier to change in the future. So for my FoodDatabase data access layer I'd create a "MinMaxCalories" class containing `int min, int max`, and for my SalaryDatabase I'd create a separate "MinMaxDollars" class also containing `int min, int max`. If you use the same generic class in both cases, you will run into trouble trying to expand the Salary database with new data. Therefore I advice to never use generics for domain information.